# What is it called when an academic discipline is given human attributes as if it has its own agency?

Tags: phrase-requests

Okay, so I'm fairly certain that there's a specific name for this that isn't anthropomorphism or personification, but instead some kind of logical fallacy or something similar... Consider:

- "Political science desires to be referred to as a hard science."
- "Sociology has learned a lot from psychology."
- "Biology saves lives."

At first I thought this was the pathetic fallacy, but I think that's incorrect now after looking at the specific situation more clearly.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [*synecdoche*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche)?

Comment: One has to be careful that one doesn't confuse error (a fallacy) with an accepted literary (eg personification) and/or grammatical (eg deletion) device.

Comment: @Hellion No "synecdoche" is quite a different thing, as that dictionary entry illustrates. But nor do I think there is a term for what is being sought here. "Anthropomorphism" gets close. But the OED only seems to recognise its application to animals or concrete objects, not to abstract things such as academic disciplines.

Comment: @WS2  It can certainly be argued that 'Sociology has learned a lot from psychology.' is metonymy, with 'sociology' standing in for 'students and experts studying sociology' as with 'Whitehall did not comment'. It is possible that OP's title is misleading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fair, of course this depends on context. I'm referring to the use in a biological, chemical, or mathematical journal, where the subject shouldn't be given its own agency. I don't think its synecdoche either... I feel like I same across that as well at some point.

Comment: Metonymy is very broad. As the 'Whitehall' example shows, it's often a form of abbreviation, using a salient associated feature to represent the people often working there etc. Where the token is the discipline people are involved in, there may well be a more precise term. / But note that 'agency' is held by some to demand some volitional content, but not by others, who would have the subclass 'volitional agent'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure I agree with you there - re the metonymy. "Economics speaks a different language to Accountancy - one is a science the other an art". How can "Economics" and "Accountancy" be referring to the people who practise them? The point being made is that the disciplines differ in nature.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not saying that the tenors are always people (note the 'etc'). 'The kettle boiled': tenor _water in the kettle_; vehicle 'kettle'. But in your example, 'Economics speaks a different language ...' must mean 'The basic tenets, aims and methodologies of economists are different from ...' Economics entails economists. Disciplines require people engaged in them.

Comment: Presumably, the consolidated communicated utterances of the entire company of political scientists is, in balance, a 'voice' of the entity, rather than merely an aggregate of the utterances of the separate individuals. The balanced 'voice' of the entire company will be a different thing than any one of the individuals involved. So it becomes an entity that speaks, as it were.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We are probably arguing about angels on a pin head here. But as I understand it, if a science e.g "physics" is actually a shortened way of saying "the combined documented knowledge of all physicists who have ever lived", then "physics says" is metonymy. However if "physics" exists as an abstract entity in  its own right, then "physics says" is anthropomorphism. The OED defines "physics" as "The Aristotelian system of natural science". Hence it seems to me to be a "system" that would still exist, even if man went the way of the dinosaurs. Hence I favour "anthropomorphism".

Comment: @WS2 As I usually try to be, I was careful here.  "It can certainly be argued that 'Sociology has learned a lot from psychology' is metonymy." NOT " 'Sociology has learned a lot from psychology' must be regarded as  metonymy". OP in their title seems to assume the investing-with-volitional-or-at-least-agentive-attributes interpretation in their examples, but 'England lost 4-0' is merely shorthand, so the assumption needs to be given supporting argument.

Comment: A related and obviously metonymic term is 'the press' as in 'the press are turning against the General'. Here, 'the press' has come to be synonymous with 'people [who make the decisions] in the newspaper industry'. With 'the media', the vehicle 'media' (for the tenor  '[significant] people in the media industry') we have an example even closer to those OP gives.

Comment: @edwin Ashworth I've absolutely no disagreement with 'The press', 'Westminster acts as if...', 'Parliament thinks...'etc.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth But how about things like 'Logic dictates that...', 'Reason demands...' etc. The scientific disciplines seem to me to be in the same category as those.

Comment: 'Logic dictates that' is a somethinged paraphrase of 'people applying logic here must inevitably deduce that  (/ decide to ...)', etc. 'Metonymy' needs only the loosest of associations. I'm not saying that there may not be a less broad term here, nor that some people may want to invoke a philosophical concept somewhat akin to anthropomorphism. // Trivially, if 'logic dictates that' has the decoding 'The Fuhrer is having cream-cakes for tea' in the Eminga Code, it's pointless to look for deep philosophical subtexts. // Again, I'm not saying that looking for philosophical subtexts is wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nordquist, at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/ontological-metaphor-term-1691453), has an article presenting Lakoff and Johnson's classification of metaphors:

> **Ontological metaphor** (a figure that provides "ways of viewing events, activities, emotions, ideas, etc., as entities and
>   substances") is one of the three overlapping categories of conceptual
>   metaphors identified by George Lakoff and Mark Johnson in Metaphors We
>   Live By (1980).
>
> An ontological metaphor is a type of metaphor (or figurative
>   comparison) in which something concrete is projected onto something
>   abstract.
>
> The other two categories are structural metaphor and orientational
>   metaphor.
>
> Ontological metaphors "are so natural and persuasive in our thought,"
>   say Lakoff and Johnson, "that they are usually taken as self-evident,
>   direct descriptions of mental phenomena." Indeed, they say,
>   ontological metaphors "are among the most basic devices we have for
>   comprehending our experience."

The article goes on to discuss the various purposes of ontological metaphors:

> Ontological metaphors serve various purposes, and the various kinds of
>   metaphors there are reflect the kinds of purposes served. Take the
>   experience of rising prices, which can be metaphorically viewed as an
>   entity via the noun inflation. This gives us a way of referring to the
>   experience:
>
> INFLATION IS AN ENTITY
>
> *Inflation is lowering our standard of living.*
>
> *If there's much more inflation, we'll never survive.*
>
> *We need to combat inflation.*
>
> *Inflation is backing us into a corner.*
>
> *Inflation is taking its toll at the checkout counter and the gas pump.*
>
> *Buying land is the best way of dealing with inflation.*
>
> *Inflation makes me sick.*
>
> In these cases, viewing inflation as an entity allows us to refer to
>   it, quantify it, identify a particular aspect of it, see it as a
>   cause, act with respect to it, and perhaps even believe that we
>   understand it. Ontological metaphors like this are necessary for even
>   attempting to deal rationally with our experiences."
>
> (George Lakoff and Mark Johnson, Metaphors We Live By. The University
>   of Chicago Press, 1980)

So the way political science, sociology, psychology, biology, ... logic, reason ... are used above fits with this definition of 'ontological metaphor'. It should be pointed out, though, that personification is seen as one form of ontological metaphor in the article.

Comment: I was casting around for something like ***prosopopoeia,*** but this is a far, far better thing!